# TFF: train_test_client_split to partition each client data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-federated

I am building a federated learning model.
I have written the code below, but I keep getting the error, which is also not true
please let me know how to use the function `train_test_client_split` properly?

```
@tf.function
def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn(dataset_path):
   return tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(
     dataset_path, record_defaults=record_defaults, header=True )

source = tff.simulation.datasets.FilePerUserClientData(
  dataset_paths, create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn)
print(source.client_ids)
>> ['client_0', 'client_1', 'client_2']

@classmethod
def from_clients_and_fn():
    client_ids: Iterable[str]
    create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn: Callable[[str], tf.data.Dataset]

Splitting=source.from_clients_and_tf_fn(['client_0', 'client_1', 'client_2'],create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn)

source.train_test_client_split(client_data=Splitting,
                               num_test_clients=1)
```

`NotFoundError: client_1; No such file or directory [Op:IteratorGetNext]`

The file is there and the path is correct, but I don't know what it the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the correct data structure. Try something like the following.

##### Create dummy data

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
# Dummy data
samples = 5
data = [[tf.random.uniform((samples,), maxval=50, dtype=tf.int32).numpy().tolist(),
        tf.random.uniform((samples,), maxval=50, dtype=tf.int32).numpy().tolist(),
        tf.random.uniform((samples,), maxval=50, dtype=tf.int32).numpy().tolist(),
        tf.random.uniform((samples,), maxval=50, dtype=tf.int32).numpy().tolist(),
        tf.random.normal((samples,)).numpy().tolist(),
        tf.random.normal((samples,)).numpy().tolist(),
        tf.random.normal((samples,)).numpy().tolist(),
        tf.random.normal((samples,)).numpy().tolist(),
        tf.random.normal((samples,)).numpy().tolist(),
        tf.random.normal((samples,)).numpy().tolist(),
        tf.random.uniform((samples,), maxval=50, dtype=tf.int32).numpy().tolist(),
        tf.random.uniform((samples,), maxval=50, dtype=tf.int32).numpy().tolist()]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.explode(list(df.columns))
df.to_csv('client1.csv', index= False)
df.to_csv('client2.csv', index= False)
```

##### Load, process, and split data:

```
record_defaults = [int(), int(), int(), int(), float(),float(),float(),float(),float(),float(), int(), int()]

@tf.function
def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn(dataset_path):
   return tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(dataset_path, record_defaults=record_defaults, header=True)
   
@tf.function
def add_parsing(dataset):
  def parse_dataset(*x):
    return OrderedDict([('label', x[:-1]), ('features', x[1:-1])])
  return dataset.map(parse_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

dataset_paths = {'client1': '/content/client1.csv', 'client2': '/content/client2.csv'}
source = tff.simulation.datasets.FilePerUserClientData(
  dataset_paths, create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn) 

# Make sure the client ids are tensor strings when splitting data.
source._client_ids = [tf.cast(c, tf.string) for c in source.client_ids] 
source = source.preprocess(add_parsing)

train, test = source.train_test_client_split(source, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, originally, I have my data in `CSV` files. Why did you propose using `df.to_csv`?

Comment: No.. don’t get it confused .. I was just creating dummy csv files because I did not have your data.. the create dummy data part you can ignore .. it was for demonstration purposes

Comment: Fantastic! it seems it works. I was tryna understand the code. What dose `1` mean in the `train_test_client_split(source, 1)`

Comment: One is the number of splits since I only have to clients I get one for training and one for testing

Comment: Aha, so the splitting is per clients! I was thinking that the splitting is on the data level, meaning, the splitting will be base on each client data not on all of the client as a whole. Well thanks and I will make sure to understand this.

Comment: Not too sure so just experiment a bit