# splitting the data into training and testing in federated learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-federated

I am new in federated learning
I am currently experimenting with a model by following the official TFF documentation. But I am stuck with an issue and hope I find some explanation here.

I am using my own dataset, the data are distributed in multiple files, each file is a single client (as I am planning to structure the model). and the dependant and independent variables have been defined.

**Now, my question is how can I split the data into training and testing sets in each client(file) in federated learning? like what we -normally- do in the centralized ML models**
The following code is what I have implemented so far:
*note* my code is inspired by the official documentation and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71289273/tff-train-test-client-split-to-partition-each-client-data) which is almost similar to my application, but it aims to split the clients as training and testing clients itself while my aim is to split the data inside these clients.

```
dataset_paths = {
  'client_0': '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/1.csv',
  'client_1': '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/2.csv',
  'client_2': '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/3.csv'
}
record_defaults = [int(), int(), int(), int(), float(),float(),float(),
                   float(),float(),float(), int(), int(),float(),float(),int()]

@tf.function
def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn(dataset_path):
   return tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(dataset_path,
                                          record_defaults=record_defaults,
                                          header=True)

@tf.function
def add_parsing(dataset):
  def parse_dataset(*x):
    ## x defines the dependant varable & y defines the independant 
    return OrderedDict([('x', x[-1]), ('y', x[1:-1])])
  return dataset.map(parse_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

source = tff.simulation.datasets.FilePerUserClientData(
  dataset_paths, create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn) 

source = source.preprocess(add_parsing)
## Creat the the datasets from client data 
dataset_creation=source.create_tf_dataset_for_client(source.client_ids[0-2])
print(dataset_creation)
>>> _VariantDataset element_spec=OrderedDict([('x', TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), ('y', (TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)))])>
## Convert the x into array(I think it is necessary for spliting to training and testing sets ) 
test= tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.numpy(),next(iter(dataset_creation)))
print(test)
>>> OrderedDict([('x', 1), ('y', (0, 1, 9, 85.0, 7.75, 85.0, 95.0, 75.0, 50.0, 6))])
```

My understanding to supervised ML is to split the data into training and testing sets as in the below code, I am not sure how to do this in Federated learning and whether it will work this way or not?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 42)
```

So, please I am looking for an explanation for this issue so I can proceed to the training phase.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you have an example of which data you want to split?

Comment: Hi, @AloneTogether I have updated the question, I hope it is clear now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/building_your_own_federated_learning_algorithm). You should be able to create two datasets (train and test) based on the clients and their data:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff
from collections import OrderedDict

record_defaults = [int(), int(), int(), int(), float(),float(),float(),float(),float(),float(), int(), int()]

@tf.function
def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn(dataset_path):
   return tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(dataset_path, record_defaults=record_defaults, header=True)
   
@tf.function
def add_parsing(dataset):
  def parse_dataset(*x):
    return OrderedDict([('label', x[:-1]), ('features', x[1:-1])])
  return dataset.map(parse_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

def split_train_test(client_ids):
  train, test = [], []
  for x in client_ids:
    d = source.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x)
    d_length = d.reduce(0, lambda x,_: x+1).numpy()
    d = d.shuffle(d_length)
    train.append(list(d.take(int(d_length*.8)))) 
    test.append(list(d.skip(int(d_length*.2))))
  return train[0], test[0]

dataset_paths = {'client1': '/content/client1.csv', 'client2': '/content/client2.csv', 
                 'client3': '/content/client2.csv', 'client4': '/content/client2.csv'}
source = tff.simulation.datasets.FilePerUserClientData(
  dataset_paths, create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn) 

client_ids = sorted(source.client_ids)

federated_train_data, federated_test_data = split_train_test(client_ids)
print(*federated_train_data, sep='\n')
```

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=24>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=17>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=27>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=4>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.17308392>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.889401>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.6235029>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.56010467>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-1.0171211>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.43558818>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=40>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=14>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=8>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=32>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=14>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=11>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.91828436>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.29887632>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.4598584>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-1.1088414>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.4057387>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-2.1537204>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=15>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=45>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=11>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=17>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=17>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.93560874>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-2.4382026>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-1.7638668>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.65431964>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.7130539>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.96356>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=15>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=18>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=42>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=27>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=34>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=8>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.3965425>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.2588629>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.84179455>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.114052325>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.9591451>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.94621265>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=28>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=7>)
```

If you follow the the tutorial I linked, you should be able to feed the split data directly to `tff.learning.from_keras_model`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I want to ask, is there another way to append the train and test data, I want to take 80/20% of each client since the size of the data is not the same in all of the clients.

Comment: this means it only takes from the first rows and skips from the last, does not shuffle or take the data randomly?

Comment: One last question, using `tff.learning.from_keras_model` to pass the `federated_train_data[0].element_spec` rises the error `The top-level structure in `input_spec` must contain exactly two top-level elements, as it must specify type information for both inputs to and predictions from the model`. What does it mean?

Comment: @Rayan kindly ask a new question regarding this query since it has nothing to do with your original question and it’s hard to answer it without more details.

Comment: Can you explain what does `d.reduce(0, lambda x,_: x+1).numpy()` mean and why did you include it in the code?

Comment: That's right, but I found out that the function returns number of the client not the number of samples in each client. I print (len(train)) and it return only 3. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. @Rayan you are forgetting that each element in train is a a tf.data.Dataset

Comment: yes, it is, bec we used ` create_tf_dataset_for_client` with each client, and then append it to the train and test. the result, train, and test have the same number of clients.